# Grub prompt after installing AV Linux on old Ubuntu partition of dual boot (with Win 10) machine

Tags: linux, windows-10, installation, multi-boot, grub

I installed AV Linux on a prior Ubuntu partition on dual boot computer. My aim was/is to be able to dual boot AV Linux and Windows 10. I do not wish to lose the existing Windows installation.

After installing AV Linux on partition hda7 (the old ubuntu partition) and after rebooting the computer, it enters a GNU GRUB version 2.02 prompt. I was able to determine that the Windows installation is OK by booting in to it with:

```
chainloader /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

and then

```
boot
```

Running ls at the grub prompt yields:

```
(proc) (hd0) (hd0,gpt7) (hd0,gpt6) (hd0,gpt5) (hd0,gpt4) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
```

I have not yet managed to boot in to the new AV Linux installation, nor fix the boot loader. I have an AV Linux live USB stick at hand to do any editing.

Comment: I successfully booted in too the AV linux partition on sda7. So now I need to fix the boot loader

Comment: I still cannot fix the grub boot loader. Once booted into AV Linux, I have tried using grub-customizer. Everything looks fine with both the Debian and Windows partitions showing. I save the configuration, reboot and I am returned to the grub prompt, whereupon i have to boot manually back in to Linux. I notice in the BIOS that "ubuntu" is still listed in the boot priority sequence. Can anyone please help?